# DB2 service does not start

Tags: windows, service, db2

I have installed DB2 Developer Edition on a Windows 10 machine. The DB2 instance is set to start as a service. When I attempt to start the service, I get the following error:

[image: DB2 Service Startup Error]

When I open db2diag.log, I can see these "Severe" errors:

```
2020-02-19-09.02.15.388000+060 I4802F420            LEVEL: Severe
PID     : 13992                TID : 6588           PROC : db2syscs.exe
INSTANCE: DB2                  NODE : 000
HOSTNAME: Honza
EDUID   : 6588                 EDUNAME: db2sysc
FUNCTION: DB2 UDB, base sys utilities, sqlePreInitSysCtlr, probe:4491
MESSAGE : ZRC=0x870F00C8=-2029059896=SQLO_UNKCPCC
          "unknown code page, or country code."

2020-02-19-09.02.15.389000+060 I5224F569            LEVEL: Severe
PID     : 13992                TID : 6588           PROC : db2syscs.exe
INSTANCE: DB2                  NODE : 000
HOSTNAME: Honza
EDUID   : 6588                 EDUNAME: db2sysc
FUNCTION: DB2 UDB, base sys utilities, sqlePreInitSysCtlr, probe:4675
MESSAGE : ZRC=0x870F00C8=-2029059896=SQLO_UNKCPCC
          "unknown code page, or country code."
DATA #1 : String, 17 bytes
syscState.preInit
DATA #2 : Hexdump, 8 bytes
0x0000004C0BDFF828 : 8100 0038 0800 0000                        ...8....

2020-02-19-09.02.15.390000+060 I5795F413            LEVEL: Severe
PID     : 13992                TID : 6588           PROC : db2syscs.exe
INSTANCE: DB2                  NODE : 000
HOSTNAME: Honza
EDUID   : 6588                 EDUNAME: db2sysc
FUNCTION: DB2 UDB, base sys utilities, sqleSysCtlr, probe:3496
MESSAGE : ZRC=0x870F00C8=-2029059896=SQLO_UNKCPCC
          "unknown code page, or country code."

2020-02-19-09.02.15.491000+060 I6210F499            LEVEL: Severe
PID     : 13992                TID : 6588           PROC : db2syscs.exe
INSTANCE: DB2                  NODE : 000
HOSTNAME: Honza
EDUID   : 6588                 EDUNAME: db2sysc
FUNCTION: DB2 UDB, base sys utilities, sqleSysCtlr, probe:3948
MESSAGE : ZRC=0x870F00C8=-2029059896=SQLO_UNKCPCC
          "unknown code page, or country code."
DATA #1 : <preformatted>
System Controller is exiting with RC =-2029059896, Erorr=0
```

Apparently, there is some problem with the DB2 code page / country code settings. Windows Event Viewer does not shed light on this - there are only errors indicating Windows could not start the DB2 service because the service terminated unexpectedly.

I tried to install DB2 Express edition and it exhibits the same problem.

Comment: Your question is about configuration not programming. Better to never hide error messages inside graphics when asking for help, because the error messages are not then searchable. Use plain text instead.  You should edit your question to show the output of the `db2level` command, and also show the output (as text) of the `winver` command showing the build of win10 and edition. Also, what is your locale (regional settings) for windows?

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question. The problem was in checked "Beta: Use Unicode UTF-8 for worldwide language support" checkbox in Windows Administrative language settings (Control Panel > Region > Administrative > Change System Locale > Beta: Use Unicode UTF-8 for worldwide language support.).

If you experience "unknown code page, or country code." issue with DB2, make sure the checkbox is unchecked.

Windows 10 Administrative Language Settings:
[image: 1]